Animated native splash screen in Android/Flutter
I'm very new to Flutter and Android apps (seasoned dev in other languages, Java, C++, etc) and I've been following a few tutorials online on how it all works. One thing I've been trying to do as a first exercise, is to remove the 'F' Flutter logo when the Android app starts up (from a cold start). I've seen several answers for this seemingly popular question, but it seems either people haven't quite got the full idea of the question or the post is out of date and using older code/versions.
I know it's possible to replace the 'F' with an animated splash screen because it's fairly squarely described here and shown with a little video snippet, but after trying this, I still get the F Flutter logo whilst the Flutter engine loads, then my splash screen and then the home screen (which at the moment is the default Flutter 'clicked n times' app).
So I've looked at this: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen and I've followed (and copied) this: https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/android_splash_screen, but all I see is the Flutter logo on white whilst the app is starting up, then a merged logo on top and then the home screen.
Is it actually possible to completely replace the 'F' splash screen whilst the engine is starting up in the latest version(s) of Flutter/Android and has anyone seen a more up to date example/tutorial?
Thanks

I saw your question and it got me curious about how to approach it. So, I created a repository with a demo and implementation that might be helpful to you.
The readme file is in Portuguese, but don't worry - all the content is written in English. I hope it can be useful for you!

Wow, thanks for doing that. Can you write the rest of my app please? ☺️

lol! your question was a nice study case. but from now on is with you!
